# Bing map cannot display

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, bing-maps

I want to upload a Bing map on my project(MVC3 and Razor engine). I have Create and Edit Views to deal with dinner as well as display bing map. The problem is that only Edit view can display the map while Create view cannot. But both of the views render the same particial view called "DinnerForm". I am wondering why cause this problem.

The Create view

```
@model NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Host a dinner</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@{Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm");}
```

The Edite view

```
@model NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel


    ViewBag.Title = @Html.Encode(Model.Dinner.Title);

<h2>Edit</h2>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

@{Html.RenderPartial("DinnerForm");}
```

The DinnerForm View

```
@model NerdDinner.Models.DinnerFormViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.Title)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Latitude)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.Latitude)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.Latitude)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Longitude)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.Longitude)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.Longitude)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.EventDate)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.EventDate)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.EventDate)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.ContactPhone)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.ContactPhone)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.ContactPhone)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Address)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.Address)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.Address)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Country)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.DropDownList("Country", @Model.Countries)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Countries)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.HostedBy)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.HostedBy)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.HostedBy)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Dinner.Description)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Dinner.Description)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Dinner.Description)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </p>    
        <div id="mapDiv">    
            @{Html.RenderPartial("Map", Model.Dinner);}
        </div>

    </fieldset>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#Address").blur(function (evt) {
                $("#Latitude").val("");
                $("#Longitude").val("");

                var address = jQuery.trim($("#Address").val());
                if (address.length < 1)
                    return;

                FindAddressOnMap(address);
            });
        });
        </script>
}
```

The Map view is fine because it appears on the page of Edit.

I have a js file called NerdDinner to reach the map function. FindAddressOnMap() function is defined there.

```
function NerdDinner() { }

NerdDinner.MapDivId = 'theMap';
NerdDinner._map = null;
NerdDinner._points = [];
NerdDinner._shapes = [];

NerdDinner.LoadMap = function (latitude, longitude, onMapLoaded) {
    NerdDinner._map = new VEMap(NerdDinner.MapDivId);

    var options = new VEMapOptions();

    options.EnableBirdseye = false

    // Makes the control bar less obtrusize.
    this._map.SetDashboardSize(VEDashboardSize.Small);

    if (onMapLoaded != null)
        NerdDinner._map.onLoadMap = onMapLoaded;

    if (latitude != null && longitude != null) {
        var center = new VELatLong(latitude, longitude);
    }

    NerdDinner._map.LoadMap(center, null, null, null, null, null, null, options);
}

NerdDinner.ClearMap = function () {
    NerdDinner._map.Clear();
    NerdDinner._points = [];
    NerdDinner._shapes = [];
}

NerdDinner.LoadPin = function (LL, name, description) {
    var shape = new VEShape(VEShapeType.Pushpin, LL);

    //Make a nice Pushpin shape with a title and description
    shape.SetTitle("<span class=\"pinTitle\"> " + escape(name) + "</span>");

    if (description !== undefined) {
        shape.SetDescription("<p class=\"pinDetails\">" + escape(description) + "</p>");
    }

    NerdDinner._map.AddShape(shape);
    NerdDinner._points.push(LL);
    NerdDinner._shapes.push(shape);
}

NerdDinner.FindAddressOnMap = function (where) {
    var numberOfResults = 1;
    var setBestMapView = true;
    var showResults = true;
    var defaultDisambiguation = true;

    NerdDinner._map.Find("", where, null, null, null,
                         numberOfResults, showResults, true, defaultDisambiguation,
                         setBestMapView, NerdDinner._callbackForLocation);
}

NerdDinner._callbackForLocation = function (layer, resultsArray, places, hasMore, VEErrorMessage) {
    NerdDinner.ClearMap();

    if (places == null) {
        NerdDinner._map.ShowMessage(VEErrorMessage);
        return;
    }

    //Make a pushpin for each place we find
    $.each(places, function (i, item) {
        var description = "";
        if (item.Description !== undefined) {
            description = item.Description;
        }
        var LL = new VELatLong(item.LatLong.Latitude,
                        item.LatLong.Longitude);

        NerdDinner.LoadPin(LL, item.Name, description);
    });

    //Make sure all pushpins are visible
    if (NerdDinner._points.length > 1) {
        NerdDinner._map.SetMapView(NerdDinner._points);
    }

    //If we've found exactly one place, that's our address.
    //lat/long precision was getting lost here with toLocaleString, changed to toString
    if (NerdDinner._points.length === 1) {
        $("#Latitude").val(NerdDinner._points[0].Latitude.toString());
        $("#Longitude").val(NerdDinner._points[0].Longitude.toString());
    }
}

NerdDinner.FindDinnersGivenLocation = function (where) {
    NerdDinner._map.Find("", where, null, null, null, null, null, false,
                         null, null, NerdDinner._callbackUpdateMapDinners);
}


NerdDinner.FindMostPopularDinners = function (limit) {
    $.post("/Search/GetMostPopularDinners", { "limit": limit }, NerdDinner._renderDinners, "json");
}

NerdDinner._callbackUpdateMapDinners = function (layer, resultsArray, places, hasMore, VEErrorMessage) {
    var center = NerdDinner._map.GetCenter();

    $.post("/Search/SearchByLocation",
           { latitude: center.Latitude, longitude: center.Longitude },
           NerdDinner._renderDinners,
           "json");
}


NerdDinner._renderDinners = function (dinners) {
    $("#dinnerList").empty();

    NerdDinner.ClearMap();

    $.each(dinners, function (i, dinner) {

        var LL = new VELatLong(dinner.Latitude, dinner.Longitude, 0, null);

        // Add Pin to Map
        NerdDinner.LoadPin(LL, _getDinnerLinkHTML(dinner), _getDinnerDescriptionHTML(dinner));

        //Add a dinner to the <ul> dinnerList on the right
        $('#dinnerList').append($('<li/>')
                        .attr("class", "dinnerItem")
                        .append(_getDinnerLinkHTML(dinner))
                        .append($('<br/>'))
                        .append(_getDinnerDate(dinner, "mmm d"))
                        .append(" with " + _getRSVPMessage(dinner.RSVPCount)));
    });

    // Adjust zoom to display all the pins we just added.
    if (NerdDinner._points.length > 1) {
        NerdDinner._map.SetMapView(NerdDinner._points);
    }

    // Display the event's pin-bubble on hover.
    $(".dinnerItem").each(function (i, dinner) {
        $(dinner).hover(
            function () { NerdDinner._map.ShowInfoBox(NerdDinner._shapes[i]); },
            function () { NerdDinner._map.HideInfoBox(NerdDinner._shapes[i]); }
        );
    });

    function _getDinnerDate(dinner, formatStr) {
        return '<strong>' + _dateDeserialize(dinner.EventDate).format(formatStr) + '</strong>';
    }

    function _getDinnerLinkHTML(dinner) {
        return '<a href="' + dinner.Url + '">' + dinner.Title + '</a>';
    }

    function _getDinnerDescriptionHTML(dinner) {
        return '<p>' + _getDinnerDate(dinner, "mmmm d, yyyy") + '</p><p>' + dinner.Description + '</p>' + _getRSVPMessage(dinner.RSVPCount);
    }

    function _dateDeserialize(dateStr) {
        return eval('new' + dateStr.replace(/\//g, ' '));
    }


    function _getRSVPMessage(RSVPCount) {
        var rsvpMessage = "" + RSVPCount + " RSVP";

        if (RSVPCount > 1)
            rsvpMessage += "s";

        return rsvpMessage;
    }
}

NerdDinner.dragShape = null;
NerdDinner.dragPixel = null;

NerdDinner.EnableMapMouseClickCallback = function () {
    NerdDinner._map.AttachEvent("onmousedown", NerdDinner.onMouseDown);
    NerdDinner._map.AttachEvent("onmouseup", NerdDinner.onMouseUp);
    NerdDinner._map.AttachEvent("onmousemove", NerdDinner.onMouseMove);
}

NerdDinner.onMouseDown = function (e) {
    if (e.elementID != null) {
        NerdDinner.dragShape = NerdDinner._map.GetShapeByID(e.elementID);
        return true;
    }
}

NerdDinner.onMouseUp = function (e) {
    if (NerdDinner.dragShape != null) {
        var x = e.mapX;
        var y = e.mapY;
        NerdDinner.dragPixel = new VEPixel(x, y);
        var LatLong = NerdDinner._map.PixelToLatLong(NerdDinner.dragPixel);
        $("#Latitude").val(LatLong.Latitude.toString());
        $("#Longitude").val(LatLong.Longitude.toString());
        NerdDinner.dragShape = null;

        NerdDinner._map.FindLocations(LatLong, NerdDinner.getLocationResults);
    }
}

NerdDinner.onMouseMove = function (e) {
    if (NerdDinner.dragShape != null) {
        var x = e.mapX;
        var y = e.mapY;
        NerdDinner.dragPixel = new VEPixel(x, y);
        var LatLong = NerdDinner._map.PixelToLatLong(NerdDinner.dragPixel);
        NerdDinner.dragShape.SetPoints(LatLong);
        return true;
    }
}

NerdDinner.getLocationResults = function (locations) {
    if (locations) {
        var currentAddress = $("#Dinner_Address").val();
        if (locations[0].Name != currentAddress) {
            var answer = confirm("Bing Maps returned the address '" + locations[0].Name + "' for the pin location. Click 'OK' to use this address for the event, or 'Cancel' to use the current address of '" + currentAddress + "'");
            if (answer) {
                $("#Dinner_Address").val(locations[0].Name);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you add the element where you defined FindAddressOnMap() as well as explain why there is something inside the mapDiv element?

Comment: HI, I uploaded the js file where FindAddressOnMap() defined there. Regarding to the mapDiv element, I had a css file and I defined the position of mapDiv(use fo displaying map) there.

Comment: I found it curious to have difference on the EditView, the ViewBag.Title property is not manipulated between @{ }.
I'm looking the rest of your code, but this is the only difference between the two views.